# Use class with arrayadapter

Tags: android

I have a class like this

```
class User
{
    public String name,username,bio;
    public Integer uid;
    public User (String c_name,String c_username,String c_bio,Integer c_uid)
    {
        name = c_name;
        username = c_username;
        bio = c_bio;
        uid = c_uid;
    }
    public String toString () { return "username:"+username+",name:"+name+","+"bio:"+bio+",uid:"+uid; }
}
```

and I want to use this class with arrayadapter.This is my arrayadapter:

```
conversationsAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<User>(this,0) {
    public View getChatListView(int c_position,View c_convertView,ViewGroup c_parent) {
        if (c_convertView == null) {
            c_convertView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.random_bars,null);
        }
        return c_convertView;
    }
};
ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.conversationList);
if (listView1 == null) {
    Log.w("main","listnull");

}else{
    Log.w("main","listnotnull");
    listView1.setAdapter(conversationsAdapter);
}
```

I am adding data with this line:

```
conversationsAdapter.add(new User("test","test","test",0));
```

But my app is crashing.Log cat:

```
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679): Process: com.impact.ribony, PID: 2679
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2309)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:939)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1456)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-21 16:58:36.601: E/AndroidRuntime(2679):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I fix this problem ? I didn't understand what is this errors ?

Comment: just pass a valid layout resource instead of 0 i.e android.R.layout.simple_list_item

Comment: First I suggest creating a regular class rather than an anonymous one. For one thing, this allows you more control over the constructors you can add to the class.

Comment: Second, since you are not using any of the facilities provided by `ArrayAdapter`, you should consider extending `BaseAdapter` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason for your error is that you have a method named `getChatListView()` that inflates the view for each row in the list. Android expects a method named `getView()` instead. If you change the name as well as make sure you provide the correct parameters, this will fix your error.

However, I believe you are not using `ArrayAdapter` correctly. You have several alternatives:

1. Use one of the `ArrayAdapter` constructors that takes a layout id as well as a text view id. This will leverage `ArrayAdapter` to do all the heavy lifting for you.
2. Extend `BaseAdapter` instead. This will give you more flexibility without getting confused by the extra stuff that `ArrayAdapter` does for you. For one thing, you can inflate a custom view with more than just a single `TextView`.

Comment: I used getView instead getChatListView and problem resolved.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an ArrayAdapter without a layout resource.
[ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int)) with:

- context:      The current context.
- resource:    The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.

You could use this for example:

```
new ArrayAdapter<User>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values)
```

Comment: Updated answer. I forgot that you should specify the resource id of the TextView

Comment: Which textview ? I didn't understand this method.

Comment: If you read the document, you will see that an ArrayAdapter needs a Context, a layout resource id (which will be inflated), a resource id (specifying the textview id inside the layout) and a collection of objects (to be displayed).    (the TextView resource id being optional)

Comment: But I have one more arrayadapter and I am using it like this : http://pastebin.com/ib5hL4zR and working.Why this is not working ?

Comment: Thast one is a custom ArrayAdapter, because you override the `getView()` method. So you don't have to provide a layout resource id. You are in charge of inflating the views. (cf. `convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.random_bars, null);`)

Comment: When I try to override my getChatListView method I am getting this error : The method getChatListView(int, View, ViewGroup) of type new ArrayAdapter<User>(){} must override or implement a supertype method. Can I fix it ?

Comment: getChatListView is not a method from the ArrayAdapter class. `getView` is one

Comment: I changed getChatListView to getView and added @Override then it worked.Thank you.